# Ho to convert date "2019-12-06 04:21:13.0" using to_date in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

I am able to get date using `to_date('2019-12-06 04:21:13', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`, but I have `"2019-12-06 04:21:13.0"` as an input date.

I am also not sure what last 0 means,
getting

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

for the formats I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options.  First, `date`s don't support fractions of a second.  So, if you want this information, then convert to a `timestamp`:

```
select to_timestamp('2019-12-06 04:21:13.0', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

Otherwise, remove that part of the string:

```
select to_date(substr('2019-12-06 04:21:13.0', 1, 19) 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```